# Why are 3 inches mountain bike handlebar hard to find?

Tags: mountain-bike, handlebars

I'm looking for a new handlebar, ideally 3 inches. But looking in some of the online shops it seems quite hard to get 31.8mm  bar clamp diameter handlebar with 3" rise.

Do you know if there is any reason for that?, is it maybe because people change the stem as well?

Comment: This is an interesting question but I'm not sure if it's a "practical, answerable" question. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Why not opt for a different stem with a different angle which will effectively change the "rise" on the bar to where you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I can theorize. A higher rise would mean that as you bump along, you apply more torque to the handlebar.

I bet that above a certain threshold, the rise becomes so great that preventing the handlebar from spinning in the stem becomes a real problem.

Comment: Might be more of an issue on mountain bikes, but I can't see this being any different then riding on the hoods for a road bike.  And there are plenty of situations where road bikes are going over plenty of bumps.  Not only that, but on road bikes, the torque is applied perpendicular to the center of rotation, whereas on a mountain bike, the force would more likely be pointing towards the center of rotation (or at least less perpendicular than on a road bike).

Comment: Good point. Hoods are a much bigger lever, and with a better angle. The bumps should be much less, but yeah, probably not that much less.

Comment: Almost forgot to account for the fact that road bikes don't have shocks, which would add to the torque on the bars. Almost all mountain bikes have at least front suspension which would somewhat reduce the amount of force on the bars.